# How to use public key cryptography concept for securing system?

Tags: c#, cryptography, public-key

How to implement the concept of RSA to secure the system. Can anyone give simple examples in C#.net?

Comment: Can you describe what 'securing the system' means to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET (Public Key RSA Encryption in C# .NET)

There is a small tutorial as well a project example demonstrating the basics.